# Covariance of functions of two random variables

Tags: functions, covariance, random

I am trying to show the following: Suppose that x and y follow identical and independent distribution. F(x, y) is an increasing function of x and y. Is there any way to show that the covariance between F(x, y) and F(y, x) is positive or not? Thank you so much!

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps consider a simple example for $X$ and $Y$ each taking two possible values with equal probability, and so $(F(X,Y),F(Y,X))$ having four possible equally likely pairs of values with some inequalities.

Comment: I have tried to use the approach mentioned somewhere in this forum where x is random, and F(x) and G(x) are increasing functions of x, and Cov (F(x), G(x))>0.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X,X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2,Y$ have the distribution of $X$ (same as $Y$) and are independent.
Since $F(x,y)$ is increasing in both arguments, we have
$$
[F(X_2,Y)-F(X_1,Y)][F(Y,X_2)-F(Y,X_1)]\ge 0
$$
as both multipliers are either simultaneously positive or simultaneously negative. Taking the expectation and using the fact that all the r.v. have the same distribution, we get
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[F(X,Y)F(Y,X)\right]\ge \mathbb{E} \left[F(X_2,Y)F(Y,X_1)\right].
$$
Next, by the same token,
$$
[F(X_2,Y_1)-F(X_1,Y_1)][F(Y_2,X_2)-F(Y_2,X_1)]\ge 0
$$
so
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[F(X,Y_2)F(Y_1,X)\right]\ge \mathbb{E} \left[F(X_1,Y_1)F(Y_2,X_2)\right].
$$
However,
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[F(X,Y_2)F(Y_1,X)\right]=\mathbb{E} \left[F(X_2,Y)F(Y,X_1)\right]
$$
because all $X$s and $Y$s have the same distribution. ALso, trivially,
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[F(X_1,Y_1)F(Y_2,X_2)\right]=\mathbb{E} \left[F(X,Y)\right]
\mathbb{E} \left[F(Y,X)\right]=\left(\mathbb{E} \left[F(X,Y)\right]\right)^2
$$
Combining all above, we get
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[F(X,Y)F(Y,X)\right]\ge \mathbb{E} \left[F(X,Y)\right]
\ \mathbb{E} \left[F(Y,X)\right]
$$
thus the covariance of $F(X,Y)$ and $F(Y,X)$ is indeed non-negative.